# php work out total area of a certain shape (maths)

Tags: php

I am trying to make a php product which works out area and perimeter of different shapes. There are different shapes e.g. square, rectangle, circle, triangles etc.
I currently have Total Area of all shapes, count how many shapes were worked out, highest perimeter working and there is the code for it,

edit2:

```
abstract class Shapes
{
protected $name;
protected $colour;
function __construct($n, $c)
{
$this->name   = $n;
$this->colour = $c;
}
abstract public function area();
abstract public function perimeter();
public function printShape()
{

}
```

thanks

Comment: How is `Square` defined?

Comment: updated my main post with all the details. Thanks!

Comment: @user3320800 the function `static function getname()` is not defined anywhere in the code you posted. You have one possible section of code that you haven't posted that may contain something, which is where the class `Shapes` is defined.

Comment: i've added the code where class shapes was added. and yes you're absolutely, I havent defined static function getname() anywhere. where would i define this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Shapes class, create a getter (method) called getName that returns the $name property.

e.g.

```
abstract class Shapes
{
    protected $name;
    protected $colour;

    function __construct($n, $c)
    {
        $this->name   = $n;
        $this->colour = $c;
    }

    abstract public function area();

    abstract public function perimeter();

    public function printShape()
    {
        print "<h6>The area of the " . $this->colour . " " . $this->name . " is " . $this->area(
            ) . " and the perimeter is " . $this->perimeter() . "</h6>";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect!, got it working. Thankyou Very much
is it possible to create a function which works out which shape would fit into which shape? e.g. if triangle with area of 6 would fit in a circle which was also worked out with an area of 10 just say.

Comment: @user3320800 If this answers your question, please mark it as the correct answer once you are allowed. If you have another question, you should ask another question on SO. However, please remember to search for your question first, as it has likely already been asked before.